# API for clearing all sessions in Electron?

Tags: electron

I know there is an API for clearing Session data if you have an instance of a Session, but is it possible to delete all sessions?

Answer (score 1):

It *may* be possible (I haven't tried myself):

1. Get all `WebContents` instances with [`webContents.getAllWebContents()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#webcontentsgetallwebcontents)

   > Returns WebContents[] - An array of all WebContents instances. This will contain web contents for all windows, webviews, opened devtools, and devtools extension background pages.
2. Then for each `WebContents` instance, access the `Session` instance with [`contents.session`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssession)

   > A Session used by this webContents.

So it would look like: (in the main process)

```js
const { webContents } = require('electron')
webContents.getAllWebContents().forEach(contents => {
  contents.session.clearCache(/* some arguments */);
  contents.session.clearStorageData(/* some arguments */); 
});
```

Comment: This is what I tried initially, but I don't think it works because, as I understand it, this only grabs the current active `webContents` (and the Sessions associated). If the Session that I want to delete is not active, this won't clear it.